# CSS3 Trick: blur entire webpage but without softened borders?

Tags: css, blur, css-filters

When applying a CSS3 `blur: 5px;` to my webpage the entire page has a white glow around it. I found some solutions regarding images or elements on the page where the image or element can be masked by a second div and the content could be enlarged a little and blurred to get rid of this problem.

However, since I'm applying this effect to the entire webpage this won't work.

What I'm looking for is a trick to keep every element of the page on the same position (cause the blur effect is applied on a button click) but I want the entire page and its borders to be blurry – **without the soft edges**.

```
.blur {
     filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Here is a quick mockup of what I mean … http://jsfiddle.net/z926s7f3/1/

Comment: Didn't quite get you. Wouldn't blurry borders result in soft edges? Can you show an image of the end result that you are expecting?

Comment: Well, you're right, it would result in blurry borders, but I just want the entire page blurry as background, but the edges/borders of the page should be cut of hard.

Comment: You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/z926s7f3/2/)?

Comment: Just for fun, you could zoom in to remove them: http://jsfiddle.net/z926s7f3/3/

Comment: " I just want the entire page blurry as background,"...not sure what that means...how can the page be a background? Is this for a modal that will be on top?

Comment: @Paulie_D: I think you are spot on, that's what I thought initially. OP, I guess is looking to bring up a modal on top and blur the background but without the borders becoming blurry.

Comment: @Harry I know this is an aesthetics thing but if you have a modal open that's going to have the users attention...they really aren't going to be looking at the very edges of the screen...and, even if they did, are they *really* going to notice? Still looking for a solution though...interesting project.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Fair point. I am just going to assume that OP has some specific reason for the blur :) I'd say just blurring the content (like in the fiddle I posted above) seems to be the easiest way but OP hasn't responded and so don't know if it fits their needs.

Answer (score 4):

You were on the correct path to achieve what you need but the trick is to apply the `blur` filter to the individual elements instead of the container. This would result in only contents being blurred but not the borders.

I have used `#container *` as the selector because I anticipate that you would have multiple content elements within the container and it would be difficult to mention each of them one by one.

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#container *').toggleClass('blur');
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1,
p {
  color: #fff;
}
.blur {
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <h1 id="something">Headline</h1>
  <p>
    <a href="#">Blur this page</a>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quid dubitas igitur mutare principia naturae? De illis, cum volemus. Sed quae tandem ista ratio est? Satisne vobis videor pro meo iure in vestris auribus commentatus?
    Ut pulsi recurrant?</p>
</div>
```

---

If you feel that the above is not quite upto the mark in terms of the borders being blurry then you can add an extra `blur` filter with smaller radius to the container. This would make the border look blurred but as the deviation is small the edges would look almost sharp.

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#container').toggleClass('container-blur');
  $('#container *').toggleClass('blur');
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1,
p {
  color: #fff;
}
.blur {
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
}
.container-blur {
  filter: blur(1px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <h1 id="something">Headline</h1>
  <p>
    <a href="#">Blur this page</a>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quid dubitas igitur mutare principia naturae? De illis, cum volemus. Sed quae tandem ista ratio est? Satisne vobis videor pro meo iure in vestris auribus commentatus?
    Ut pulsi recurrant?</p>
</div>
```

---

Or, you could even put the container inside a separate wrapper which has `overflow: hidden` setting. The overflow would prevent the soft edges from showing up.

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#container').toggleClass('blur');
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container,
#wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
  background: #000;
}
h1,
p {
  color: #fff;
}
.blur {
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <h1 id="something">Headline</h1>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Blur this page</a>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quid dubitas igitur mutare principia naturae? De illis, cum volemus. Sed quae tandem ista ratio est? Satisne vobis videor pro meo iure in vestris auribus commentatus?
      Ut pulsi recurrant?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```